# How to remove menus section from WordPress theme customizer

Tags: theme-development, theme-customizer, theme-options

I tried to remove Menus from WordPress customizer (see image)
[image]

I tried the following code on functions.php file and every section was removed except Menus

```
  //Theme customizer

function mytheme_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {
   //All our sections, settings, and controls will be added here

   $wp_customize->remove_section( 'title_tagline');
   $wp_customize->remove_section( 'colors');
   $wp_customize->remove_section( 'header_image');
   $wp_customize->remove_section( 'background_image');
   $wp_customize->remove_section( 'menus');
   $wp_customize->remove_section( 'static_front_page');
   $wp_customize->remove_section( 'custom_css');

}

add_action( 'customize_register', 'mytheme_customize_register' );
```

I even tried

```
$wp_customize->remove_panel( 'menus');
```

but didn't worked i m'i missing something here .appreciate any help on this thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try **nav_menus** instead of **menus** with `remove_panel()`

```
function mytheme_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {
  //All our sections, settings, and controls will be added here

  $wp_customize->remove_section( 'title_tagline');
  $wp_customize->remove_section( 'colors');
  $wp_customize->remove_section( 'header_image');
  $wp_customize->remove_section( 'background_image');
  $wp_customize->remove_panel( 'nav_menus');
  $wp_customize->remove_section( 'static_front_page');
  $wp_customize->remove_section( 'custom_css');

}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'mytheme_customize_register',50 );
```

Hope this will helps you.

Thank you!

Comment: It should be noted that the "50" here in the add_action call is important.  If it is omitted, this will not remove the nav_menus panel.

Answer (score 6):

The correct way to disable nav menus in the customizer is via the `customize_loaded_components` filter as documented on its [hook reference page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/customize_loaded_components/#comment-1005):

```
/**
 * Removes the core 'Menus' panel from the Customizer.
 *
 * @param array $components Core Customizer components list.
 * @return array (Maybe) modified components list.
 */
function wpdocs_remove_nav_menus_panel( $components ) {
    $i = array_search( 'nav_menus', $components );
    if ( false !== $i ) {
        unset( $components[ $i ] );
    }
    return $components;
}
add_filter( 'customize_loaded_components', 'wpdocs_remove_nav_menus_panel' );
```

**Important:** this filter has to be added in a plugin since it has to be added before the `setup_theme` action, which fires just before a theme's `functions.php` is loaded.

For more information, see these Trac tickets:

- [#33552](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/33552): Facilitate plugins to override Customizer features
- [#37003](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/37003): Removing `menus` support for a theme doesn't remove Menus section in Customizer

On a related note, for code that resets the customizer to a blank slate so you can add just your own items, see [Resetting the Customizer to a Blank Slate](https://make.xwp.co/2016/09/11/resetting-the-customizer-to-a-blank-slate/).

Comment: See also https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/39449 which would allow themes to configure which components are loaded.

Answer (score -1):

Edit files in admin directory on your server. Even though you may find a plugin for this job. This will help you since it will have a UI and will not restore your menu when updating your wordpress or theme.

Comment: Can you tell which files to edit?

Comment: Do not do this. Editing core files will either break upgrades or the edits will be lost when upgrading.

Comment: You don't say! I thought I said the SAME EXACT thing about updates in my answer. But THANKS for letting me know.