# Remove 'Menus' from Twenty Sixteen theme Customizer

Tags: menus, theme-customizer

I am trying to remove certain items from Twenty Sixteen Customizer using this code

```
function my_customize_register() {     
global $wp_customize;
$wp_customize->remove_section( 'colors' );
$wp_customize->remove_section( 'static_front_page' );
$wp_customize->remove_section( 'background_image' );
$wp_customize->remove_section( 'themes' ); 
$wp_customize->remove_panel( 'nav_menus' );  
} 

add_action( 'customize_register', 'my_customize_register', 11 );
```

However, for removing 'Menus' I am getting a debug message 'WP_Customiz_Manager::remove_panel was called incorrectly. Rest everything working fine.

What should I do to remove 'Menus' itme?

Comment: Try this plugin [Customize Twenty Sixteen](https://wordpress.org/plugins/customize-twenty-sixteen/)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Dharmishtha, but I found the answer in below stack which worked really well without throwing any debug errors:

[How to remove menus section from WordPress theme customizer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/250349/how-to-remove-menus-section-from-wordpress-theme-customizer)

The correct way to disable 'Menus' and 'Widgets' (in Customizer) lies in creating a plugin with below code (taken from the above mentioned post to make it convenient for others who might be searching for same answer).

```
/**
 * Removes the core 'Menus' panel from the Customizer.
 *
 * @param array $components Core Customizer components list.
 * @return array (Maybe) modified components list.
 */
function wpdocs_remove_nav_menus_panel( $components ) {
    $i = array_search( 'nav_menus', $components );
    if ( false !== $i ) {
        unset( $components[ $i ] );
    }
    return $components;
}
add_filter( 'customize_loaded_components', 'wpdocs_remove_nav_menus_panel' );
```

It can be done in other ways as well, but they throw a debug error.